# nginx autoindex: include dot (hidden) files in directory listing

Tags: nginx

The location block I'm using to statically serve files is:

```
location ~ ^/git/?(.*)$ {
    root /home/aoeu/git-webserver;
    autoindex on;
    try_files /$1 /$1/ 404;
}
```

which is mostly working, except that files and directories inside of the `/home/aoeu/git-webserver` directory that begin with a `.` character are not included in the directory listing that nginx returns when I visit the `/git/` path of by website.  Same for their respective subdirectories.

I can manually enter a dot-prefixed directory into my browser URL bar and browse it (which seems like a pretty awkward inconsistency and a possible security issue with nginx).  I just cannot see it to click on it while I am browsing its parent directory.

I would like all files to be visible, no matter what character they start with.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/i6et27/displaying_hidden_files/) that functionality is missing. The thread links to [ticket 557](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/557) from 2014, which has a patch to add a configuration option allowing dot files to be listed. Yet the ticket is open, and a quick look at the source code shows that [ngx_http_autoindex_handler()](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c#L317) simply `continue`:s whenever encountering an entry starting with a dot, still some eight-nine years later.

It is likely possible to apply the patch from the trac ticket, with or without some extra work required to adapt it to the contemporary code base.

I went with giving up on nginx for this and replaced it with lighttpd instead.

```
# lighttpd config showing dot files in directory listings.
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
dir-listing.hide-dotfiles = "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

it is now possible to use `fancyindex` module to show dot/hidden files